# Wrapper on old .NET MVC project to .NET core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Might be my question will be unusual for all of you but my current project structure and business doesn't allowing me to change it.
I have project structure which is build on .NET framework 4.5.1, we dont have web APIs, not well managed code. It is simple 3 layered architecture as UI, Business and DB Connection. 
We want to migrate this application on .NET Core in some certain phases.
In first phase we have to create Core Web Apis for that we are thinking to write wrapper on top of business logic. Rest migration will do in later phases.
Could you please let me know does it possible to write .NET core wrapper on top of .NET framework? OR does it possible to refer .NET framework .dll to .NET core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, your question is too broad. However, there's certain things you should understand:

1. ASP.NET Core is fundamentally different from ASP.NET, despite sharing "ASP.NET" in their names. There is no true 1-to-1 correlation or migration process. Creating an ASP.NET Core app is a rewrite, not an upgrade.
2. ASP.NET Core is not the same as .NET Core. An ASP.NET Core app can actually target either .NET Core or .NET Framework. If you need to utilize .NET Framework libraries, you'll likely need to target .NET Framework in your ASP.NET Core app. This of course then means that you're still tied to Windows (no cross-platform), but you can still use all the other ASP.NET Core goodness, for the most part.
3. If you're dealing with your own libraries, your first move should be to attempt to retarget those libraries to .NET Standard. You may not be able to accomplish this, depending on what APIs your libraries are utilizing from .NET, but if you can get them running on .NET Standard 2.0, then you can use them directly when targeting .NET Core.
4. I'm not sure what you ultimately mean by a "wrapper", but you cannot run both ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET in the same project, if that's what you mean.